# Arbitrarily large sized gaps in the $L$ hierarchy

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory, ordinals

**Question:** Assume $V=L$. Let $\xi < \omega_1$ be arbitrary. Then there is $\alpha < \omega_1$ such that $L_\alpha \cap P(\omega) = L_{\alpha+\xi} \cap P(\omega)$.

Here's my idea:

When $V = L$, $L_{\omega_2} \vDash ZFC-PowerSet$ (since when $V=L$ the $L$ and $H$ hierarchy coincide for uncountable cardinals (basically the proof of $GCH$)).

Since $L_{\omega_2} \vDash ZFC-Powerset$ it can develop the notions of formulas, definability, constructibility, ordinal addition, etc, and will moreover be correct about it (i.e, it's absolute). And since  $P(\omega) \subseteq L_{\omega_1} \subseteq L_{\omega_2}$, we have that

$L_{\omega_2} \vDash L_{\xi + \omega_1} \cap P(\omega) = L_{\omega_1} \cap P(\omega)$

Then take a countable $X \prec L_{\omega_2}$ such that $trcl(\{\xi\}) \subseteq X$ and apply the Mostowski collapse on $X$. By the condensation theorem this is $L_\beta$ for some $\beta \in \omega_2$. $\beta \in \omega_1$ since $L_\beta$ is countable. Moreover $\pi(\xi) = \xi \in L_\beta$ because $X$ contains the transitive closure. Finally $\omega_1$ is definable in $L_{\omega_2}$ (as the least uncountable ordinal) and thus $\omega_1 \in X$. Let $\alpha = \pi(\omega_1) \in L_\beta$. $\alpha < \omega_1$ So we then have:

$L_\beta \vDash L_{\xi + \alpha} \cap P(\omega) = L_{\alpha} \cap P(\omega)$

And again $L_\beta \vDash ZFC-Powerset$ and is absolute about the $L$-hierarchies, etc. So then we have that $L_{\xi + \alpha} \cap P(\omega) = L_\alpha \cap P(\omega)$ as desired.

I think this is mostly fine except for the absoluteness/correctness parts which I handwaved. I am usually uncomfortable and unsure when I appeal to absoluteness (feels too handwavey) like above so I just wanted to see if I made any mistakes. I think I'm mostly fine about the absoluteness of the definability and constructibility stuff. However, I'm not sure about the complexity and absoluteness of ordinal addition. Is it absolute?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is right. Ordinal addition is absolute: the ordinal successor operation is absolute, unions are absolute, and a transfinite recursion defined from absolute operations is absolute.

A couple extra things:

1. Your question about absoluteness of ordinal addition suggests a generalization, since this is pretty much the only aspect of ordinal addition you used. Let $F(\alpha,\xi)$ be any absolute operation on the ordinals with $F(\alpha, \xi)\ge \alpha$. Then for any $\xi<\omega_1$ there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $L_{F(\alpha,\xi)}\cap P(\omega) = L_{\alpha}\cap P(\omega).$
2. Even though this is under the assumption of V=L, it can be rephrased without it and the proof is similar: For any $\xi < \omega_1^L$ there is an $\alpha < \omega_1^L$ such that $L_{\alpha+\xi}\cap P(\omega) = L_\alpha\cap P(\omega).$
3. Also note that by just increasing how many ordinals we put in the elementary submodel, we can replace "there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$" with "there are unboundedly many $\alpha < \omega_1$".